# Recoil Atom and Typescript, define type and pass atom as parameter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recoiljs

I start to use recoils and typescript.

At this time, I use the default property to define each properties type of my atom :

```
 const WipStateAtom = atom({
    key: 'wipAtom',
    default: {
       data: null as IData | null,
       ex: null as IEx | null,
    }
 });
```

But is it possible to use an interface/or a type to define the atom content like :

```
export interface IWipAtom {
   data: IGameData | null,
   ex: IEx | null,
}
```

I want to pass an atom in a function but I don't want to type it as ANY :

```
const [wip, setWip] = useRecoilState(WipStateAtom);

const myFunction = (thewip: any) => { ... }
```

I prefer to strictly define its type :

```
const myFunction = (thewip: IWipAtom) => { ... }
```

Any way to type the atom ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the type during the atom creation:

```
const WipStateAtom = atom<IWipAtom>({
  key: 'wipAtom',
  default: {
    data: null as IData | null,
    ex: null as IEx | null,
  }
});
```

Comment: Shame on me... generics...